# How would you create a Users collection when apple sign in lets you hide your email

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am making a flutter app where users can sign up with email, google or apple and Im adding them to a users collection using their email as i've been told is best practice but there is a little problem, apple lets users hide their email making it impossible to link that user to any other accounts or add them to a users collection. Does a way around this problem exist?

Comment: There's a solid answer from @frankvanpuffelen but a common mistake many new developers make is to rely too much on an email address to 'link' data. e.g. they attempt to use the email address as a documentID for example. emails change and if it does, it's a mess to update all the areas where the email is used to link data, so best practice is to use the UID as Frank mentions to 'link' users to their data, and let the email address just be a property of the users document. We don't know exactly what your use case but perhaps that will help.

Answer (score 1):

If the users sign in with Firebase Authentication, they get a unique identified called a UID. It's common and idiomatic in Firebase to use this UID to associate data with that user.